# Why is $2 - (x/2)$ surjective?

Tags: functions

I know that a surjective function means that for every value in the co-domain, their is at least one value in the domain. However how can I test if the function $2 - \frac{x}{2}$ is surjective or not? The domain is  $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$

Comment: We can't answer your question.. we need more details about the domain of the function, and the co-domain of it.

Comment: You need to give a little more information about your function. For example, the function $f:\{1\} \rightarrow \mathbb R: x \mapsto 2-\frac{x}{2}$ is not surjective.

Answer (score 3):

Unless otherwise specified, this looks like the domain and range are supposed to be the real numbers.  On that assumption, you can try to solve $y=2-\frac x2$ for $x$.  If for every real $y$ you can find an appropriate $x$ it is surjective.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y = 2- \frac {x}{2}$

Solve for x to find $x = 4 - 2y$

So now you can say that $\forall y \in \mathbb {R} \exists x \in \mathbb {R} / f(x) = y$

Proof? Let x= 4-2y. Then f(x) = 2 - (4-2y)/2 = 2 - 2 + y = y.

Answer (score -1):

Another way to prove this is surjective is
As it's continuous everwhere consider $y'$, which is $-1/2$. This means the function is continuously decreasing on $R$. Thus, every image has a pre-image making it surjective

Edit:- After suggestions from Jean-Claude Arbut , I would like to add this

$\lim \limits_{x \to \infty}2-\frac{x}{2}=-\infty$
and

$\lim \limits_{x \to {-\infty}}2-\frac{x}{2}=\infty$

As noted earlier it's monotonic
Thus we have proved $y$ is surjective

Comment: $x\to\exp(-x)$ is also continuously decreasing on $\Bbb R$. You need a bit more: the limits at $\pm\infty$.

Comment: I''l add that, the continuously decreasing was just meant to show it's monotonic, hence we don;t have to worry about bounds

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!